# ledger-cli journal automated resetting virtual account

Tags: command-line-interface

i'm using ledger-cli (http://www.ledger-cli.org).
i wanna reset my virtual account balance automated like what mention in documentation section 5.10.3 Resetting a balance.

i tried like :

```
= /Income:Salary/ 
   (Asset:Budget:Utility)    = $ 1000
```

But get an error

```
Error: Unexpected char '=' (Note: inline math requires parentheses)
```

Can somebody explain how should i get this done automaticly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the first "=", not the second.

You should have the following:

`Income:Salary 
   (Asset:Budget:Utility)    = $ 1000`